# Clone and patch class in ruby

Tags: ruby

I need to create pathed copy of the class, where calls to one module method are replaced to another module method calls:

```
module Foo
    def self.check
        "foo"
    end
end

module Bar
    def self.check
        "bar"
    end
end

class Bark
    def call
        puts Foo.check
    end
end

Bark.new.call => "foo"

Meouw = Bark.dup

...

???

Meouw.new.call => "bar"
```

Any ideas how would i achieve that?

Comment: Since you say "patch" I assume that you want to modify the behavior of existing / 3rd party code. Can you explain _why_ you want to do this in the first place? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I need to get copy of library class with modified behavior, while other code depends on original implemetation. But class relies on direct calling of module methods.

Answer (score 0):

Odd problems require odd solutions. You could define `Meouw::Foo` and make it refer to `Bar`:

```
Meouw = Bark.dup
Meouw::Foo = Bar
```

This way, `Foo` within `Meouw` will resolve to `Meouw::Foo` (which is actually `::Bar`) instead of the global `::Foo`:

```
Meouw.new.call
# prints "bar"
```

Comment: Thank you, it works like a charm. But i missed something in my example - Bark class includes other modules, referencing Foo, and while using fixed to Bar in class body, mixins still using Foo :(

Comment: @crsde you can edit your question to clarify the problem. You might also want to provide some background information. There are probably other ways to approach the problem instead of redefining `Foo`.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer to the question as it was asked, but in my opinion you are trying to solve an XY problem and this is not the way to go.

What you need to do is to inject the dependency instead of hardcoding it.

```
module Foo
  def self.check
    "foo"
  end
end

module Bar
  def self.check
    "bar"
  end
end

class Bark
  def initialize(checker)
    @checker = checker
  end

  def call
    puts @checker.check
  end
end
```

and then just instantiate the `Bark` class with the module you need to get an object with the desired behavior:

```
Bark.new(Foo).call #=> "foo"
Bark.new(Bar).call #=> "bar"
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but the reason to patch first class instead of refactoring is inability to change it's code

Comment: What do you mean by "inability"? It's Ruby, you can reopen any class/module and change it. Monkey-patching is being considered a very controversial technique (for a good reason) and is largely discouraged, but for the cases like this one it might be still better than fighting with the language's object model itself.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you keep it simple and inherit from `Bark` and override the `call` method?

```
class Meow < Bark
  def call
    puts Bar.check
  end
end

Meouw.new.call

# prints "bar"
```

If you want something more meta, you can use `Class.new` as well

Comment: I can't inherit from Bark because in a real case, there is very many methods to override.

Comment: @crsde you override only what needs to be overridden. Any other (non-overridden) method will be just dispatched to the parent class implementation.